# Mass Updates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to do a mass update on short codes in SQL Server,  but it doesn't return any change:

```
SELECT DISTCINT 
    a.site_area_sc, a.site_area_n, a.site_area_rmk, d.site_n 'NAME', d.site_sc, 


UPDATE DB.DBO.bg
SET bg_sc = 'XXX-' + bg.bg_sc
FROM DB.DBO.bg 
INNER JOIN DB.DBO.site ON s.site_id = bg.site_id
WHERE site.site_sc like 'XXX-%'
  AND bg.stat_flag = 'n'
  AND s.stat_flag = 'n'
  AND bg.bg_sc not like 'XXX-%'
```

I am in need of help.

Comment: This is just a sample of the code used

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Try to run just the select part of the update.script and verify it returns any results, if not that is your problem

Comment: Have you checked that the `FROM` / `WHERE` clauses in your update statement return the rows you expect when you use it with `SELECT` instead of `UPDATE`?

Comment: What happens when you run the update as a select, `select DB.DBO.bg.bg_sc, bg.bg_sc FROM DB.DBO.bg INNER JOIN DB.DBO.site ON s.site_id = bg.site_id WHERE site.site_sc like 'XXX-%' AND bg.stat_flag = 'n' AND s.stat_flag = 'n' and bg.bg_sc not like 'XXX-%'`

Comment: As posted that update won't run. You have aliases sometimes and other times not. In some places you have site.whatever and sometimes it is s.whatever.

Comment: I used similar code earlier to update another area, again similar situation, mass update of shortcode and building

Comment: Aliases have been removed temporily for confusions sake (mine)